# Boot loader failed when installing windows on hyper-v vm

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-installation

I try to install windows 10 Pro from ISO image, on a virtual machine just created by hyper-v.
I'm running hyper-v on window 10 pro.

The problem is that the vm won't boot from DVD controller. The following image shows after a while:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved by creating a new virtual machine, with option `Generation 1`, as show bellow:
[image]